# Writing speedtest csv data to csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, speed-test

```
import speedtest
import time
import csv


def test():
    servers = []

    s = speedtest.Speedtest()

    s.get_servers(servers)
    s.get_best_server()
    s.download()
    s.upload()
    s.results.share()

    results_csv = s.results.csv()
    # csv_header = s.results.csv_header()

    print(results_csv)

    with open("results.csv", 'a') as f:

        result_writer = csv.writer(f)
        result_writer.writerow(results_csv)

    time.sleep(120)
    # 900


while True:
    test()
```

This code returns csv formatted text to terminal perfectly I'm just having trouble writing it to the csv file I defined. How would I go about getting this to work properly?

Currently it prints the results with a comma after every digit/character and creates a new row for the next entry.

Comment: Consider stating *how it works* and *how you expect it to work*

Comment: Also post any errors you may be getting.

Comment: consider using pandas.DataFrame.to_csv, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html